# Intent causing Activity to crash

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have an activity that receives .getExtras() from two different activities. The only problem is that it crashes because of the two different .getExtras() being set on that activity. How can I overcome this issue. Like could I make an activity pass some sort of unique ID to the other Activity.

Thanks

Comment: please paste son code of the Activities

Comment: When we passing intent with some data then we already defining some key there by which you can make logic from which activity the intent is called from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check if the extra of key is found then do your code like the following

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("Name"))
{
         //Write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a boolean extra from both activity and make that value true for one activity and false for other activity and when you getextra in receiving activity first get that boolean value and than get all other data base on that Key

```
Intent actA=new Intent(CurrentAct.this, ActivityA.class);  //Activity A code
actA.putExtra("Key",true);
startActivity(actA);


Intent actB=new Intent(CurrentAct.this, ActivityB.class); //Activity B code
actB.putExtra("Key",true);
startActivity(actB);


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //Receiving Activity Code
boolean mKey=extras.getBoolean("Key");
if(mKey){
   //Activity A calling
}else{
 //Activity B calling
}
```